# get a json file that a webpage is made of

Tags: html, json, code-inspection

I'm not familiar with web development but I believe this web page text content 
 https://almath123.github.io/semstyle_examples/
 is made of two JSON files mentioned in it (`semstyle_results.json` and `semstyle_results.json`) and the JSON files are completely present in ram  (If this is the correct term for referring to it) because when I disconnect the internet I can still browse the page and see the text content.

I want to download `semstyle_results.json` file. Is that possible? how can I do that?

Comment: If those files are actually part of the page composition, they're being bundled. Refresh the page with the Chrome dev tools open to the Network panel and JS selected as a filter. There are no such files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically if you visit a website you're "downloading" the content. Your browser sends a request for information and a server responds by sending you the information.  You're viewing that information locally.  Dynamic sites poll or make further requests as you browse to keep the data updated and relevant, but it's sent to you.

If you want to easily download any of the content from the website, a simple way is to open up the development tools (`CTRL` + `SHFT` + `I` on windows for Firefox and Chrome), go to a source file and click `save as`. The `network` tab shows you requests that were made which includes not just files such as `json` but also the details of the request.

Here is a screenshot locating one of the `json` files in a Chrome-based browser (Brave)

[image: json response]

Comment: the problem is that I am unable to locate file semstyle_results.json in sources of the page. Is it going to be a special folder for this type of content?

Comment: I specifically located that file in a chrome-based browser by going to `network` tab. If you click on one of the two links, you'll see the `json` that was sent there. Click 'response' to see it

Comment: I think I've got what I was looking for. thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

The webpages may not always show that they will support json or xml return of data. For example if you inspect this webpage [SEC EDGAR database](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320187/000032018720000047/) using the method described above, it shows no json link but if you append index.json at the end of the link it will return the same data in json format or xml format, if you so please.

i.e: [same website but with json endpoint](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320187/000032018720000047/index.json)

So it is always a good idea to see if the website hosts developer information. For example SEC EDGAR provides developer tools that mentions that the directory structure can be accessed via HTML, XML or JSON.

[SEC developer information](https://www.sec.gov/os/accessing-edgar-data)